# Gracenote API: List of Genres

Tags: gracenote

Is there a way to retrieve all "genre" field list? I've seen it was the case for contribution/production types: I'm using Gracenote web api.

I've also noticed that "IPGCategorie" L1/L2 values looks a lot like "Genre" field values... Is there a relation between them?

EDIT: Sorry for not pointing this before, but i'm talking about the Movie/Video API

Comment: can you update the question to include platform/sdk information?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first refer to the 'eyeQ Web API reference' document found in the following page: https://developer.gracenote.com/eyeq.

Starting from 'FIELDVALUES' section in page 17, it has the exact information you are looking for.

There are L1 and L2 IPGCATEGORY values.
The following is a sample query taken from the document.

```
<QUERIES>
 <AUTH>
   <CLIENT>client_id_string</CLIENT>
   <USER>user_id_string</USER>
 </AUTH>
 <LANG>eng</LANG>
 <QUERY CMD="FIELDVALUES">
   <FIELDNAME>IPGCATEGORY_L1</FIELDNAME>
   <MEDIASPACE>VIDEO</MEDIASPACE>
 </QUERY>
</QUERIES>
```

Comment: Hi, This was not my question.
I was asking if L1 and L2 values were the values of "GENRE" field...
I already done what you showed in your answer...
And by the way, it seems for me that it is not:
I took the id of "GENRE" field with value "Comédie", and compared it with the one given in IPGCATEGORY_L2. Actualy, it is absolutly not the same...

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of genres (or moods, or eras) you need to make a call to the "fieldvalues" API, you can see how to do it here:

https://developer.gracenote.com/rhythm-api#attribute-station

This call will give you the list of supported genres:

https://cXXXXXXX.web.cddbp.net/webapi/json/1.0/radio/fieldvalues?fieldname=RADIOGENRE&client=CLIENT_ID&user=USER_ID

You can then use the returned ID's with pygn.createRadio()

Comment: Sorry for not pointing this before, but i'm talking about the Movie/Video API